# How to get all sharedpreferences contains same name

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I would like to put together (to in spinner) all sharedpreferences that has the same name.

Now I can only get all sharedpreferences I have no idea how can i get same named sharedpreferences like alarm1, alarm2, alarm3, alarm4, alarm5.

```
final File prefsdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"shared_prefs");
String[] list = prefsdir.list();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,list);
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tum_ilaclar);
p.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to `Arrays.sort(list);`?

Comment: where are you using sharedPreferences in above code?

Comment: No i just want to get sharedpref start with alarm these are created by automatically. So spinner must contain only alarm1, alarm2, alarm3.

Comment: every sharedPreference is an alarm. it contains alarm datas.

Comment: you must check it yourself after getting all your datas from SharedPreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### List files with filter

```
final File prefsdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"shared_prefs");
String[] list = prefsdir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return filename.startsWith("alarm");
    }
});
```

### Remove file extension

This is a `FileUtil` class I have written previously. It uses the general approach to get filename from a path with/without extension. You may just use it to loop through your filtered list to get what you want.

```
package com.example.utils;

import java.io.File;

public final class FileUtil {
    public static String getFilename(String path) {
        if (path == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] segments = path.split(File.separator);
        return segments[segments.length - 1];
    }

    public static String getFilenameNoExt(String path) {
        if (path == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String filename = getFilename(path);
        int extension = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
        return (extension >= 0) ? filename.substring(0, extension) : filename;
    }

    private FileUtil(){}
}
```

Comment: it works! one more question, what if i'm using a function for trim .xml extension like `String[] list = getList(prefsdir.list());`

Comment: You mean you want to remove the extension after you get the filtered file list?

Comment: Yes, exaclty i forget to tell.

Comment: I just call this func.

`private String[] getList(String[] list) {
        String values[] = new String[list.length];
        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            String value = list[i];
            values[i]=value.contains(".xml")?value.replace(".xml",""):value;
        }
        return values;
    }`

Comment: I believe your code (extension removal) work just fine. I posted mine for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand clearly,But use for-loop for that

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();            
    for(int i=1;i<list.length;i++){
        editor.putString("alarm"+i,value);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what do you want. You can filter prefsdir.list() list like that and create your adapter.

```
ArrayList<String> filtered_list = new ArrayList<String>()
for(String item : prefsdir.list()){
   if(item.startWith("alarm")){
      filtered_list.add(item)
   }
}
```

But this is not good way to keep datas. As for me you can use a db for this. You can easy implement an [orm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) library like [activeandroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid).